# Execute Test Suite Without Refreshing Page in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm trying to create a test case in Selenium IDE. 
The idea is to split my whole test in smaller ones to help find problems in the execution.

[Example of my test suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH6Jc.png)

I've created a test suite with all my small tests inside, and I'd like that the next test starts right where the last one stopped. But in the beginning of the execution, every test refreshes the browser.

[Test Refreshing Browser on start of the execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I33N.png)

My question is:
Is it possible to run an entire test suite without refreshing the browser when a new test starts?

thanks a lot

Comment: My understanding of using test suites is that each test should be standalone, i.e. it should not depend on any other tests.

Comment: adding screenshots is bad practice and please read [mcve] and follow the same in all the post in future